# sorting date in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Our table which is using the jquery dataTables plugin, has some date columns which are not getting sorted properly.
Instead it is sorting these dates as strings. 
The format of the date incoming is - "Fri Jun 24 12:23:45 IST 2011".

Can anyone suggest how and which sorting plugin I can use to sort these correctly.

Comment: Are you sorting server side or client side?Because it's a totally different matter

Answer (score -3):

Use Jquery TableSorter. It is best in sorting currencies,dates etc. [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: for our other use cases - dataTables fares better so we need to use dataTables.

Comment: Then, You might have to write a custom plugin for datatables. Or use the plugin by [Rouman Guillox](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) to sort dd/mm/YYY hh:ii:ss - Use some hidden value for your converter ISO date to the above format. But it's bit heavy ;)